# Session Management in Express

Tags: express, passport.js, express-session

I have a `express` app with `express-session`, `session-file-store` and `passport`. When a user first logs in, server creates a `sessionID` and creates the corresponding session file. However, I have the following problems:

1. When the `User-Agent` or, `curl` sends a `cookie` with the `connect.sid`, I can't lookup the session store for the saved ID. I looked into `session-file-store` docs and could not find any methods or ways of doing so. Is there a way?
2. Is there a way to destroy or remove the session at 'logout` request?

**Edit**
As @jfriend00 suggested, I thought it best to provide more context. As mentioned earlier, I have around 3 middleware for session. This is how they are mounted:

`authserver.js`

```
// session options
const sessOpts = {
  genid: (req) => uuid(),
  store: new sessionFS(),
  secret: _secret,
  resave: false,
  saveUninitialized: true
};
// mws
authservice.use(initLogger); 
authservice.use(exprSession(sessOpts));
authservice.use(bodyParser.json());
authservice.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
authservice.use(expSanitizer()) // must follow preceeding line
authservice.use(corsHandler);
authservice.disable('x-powered-by');
authservice.disable('etag');
// session mws
authservice.use(passportInst.initialize());
authservice.use(passportInst.session());
```

This how the `passport LocalStrategy` is set:

`passport_strategies.js`

```
passport.use(new passportLocal(
(username, password, done) => {
    //console.log('In local');
    mongoHelpers.connect((cerr, db) => {
        if(!!cerr) return done(cerr);
        mongoHelpers.findUser({
            username: username,
            password: password
        }, db, (err, usrs) => {
            if(!!err) return done(err);
            if(!!!usrs) return done(null, false);
            //if(!validateUser(usrs[0], userSchema)) return done(null, false);
            //console.log('local: ' + usrs.toString());
            //console.log(usrs);
            return done(null, usrs[0]);
        });
    });
}
));
passport.serializeUser((user, done) => {
   console.log('In serializer');
   if(!!!user) {
     done(new Error("User cant be undefined in serializeUser"), null);
    //console.log("user is null");
   }
   done(null, user._id); // mongo auto id
});
passport.deserializeUser((id, done) => {
 console.log('In Dcserializer');
 console.log(id);

});
```

1. Now there are two sessions `exprSession` which is an instance of `express-session` and `passport.session()`. Are both these instances referring to the same object?
2. I am looking up the `user` collection on each authentication strategy for matching pair or username and password. This lookup is also done in another middleware down the chain. Is the second middleware redundant?|
3. In the serialize user method, I am passing the mongo id. In deserialize, I get a session ID back as `id`. If this is the session ID, is there a way to use this to destroy session?
4. When a user logs out, is it a good practice (or even done generally) to remove/unset the previously set cookie even with `maxAge` or `expires` set?

I apologize if the question seems somewhat convoluted. I am fairly new to these middleware.

Comment: With `express-session`, if you are logged in and there is a session, you can call `req.session.destroy()`.  There should be no need for you to look up the session yourself for this purpose, the express-session middleware does that for you and puts the session in `req.session` where you can just access it (if logged in with a session).

Comment: @jfriend00 I do have another problem which, would have been easier to solve (i think) with a lookup function. As I mentioned, I am using passportjs and, in `passport.deserializeUser((id, done) => { // What's id and, if this is session id, how to lookup and remove it? })`. I hope it explains.

Comment: Then, please either write a new question for that issue or edit your question to make it be the specific question you have.  passport and express-session are very widely used so any questions you have are probably already discussed somewhere as long as we know what your actual root problem is.

Comment: @jfriend00 Edited the original post.